# Checkboxes are keeping myCurrencyManager.AddNew() from working properly

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I have a fully functional Windows forms app developed with a read-only datagridview bound to an Access DB.
Databound textboxes are used to edit fields. I then added 3 Checkbox fields to the DB, datagridview and the form. Then added `chkName.DataBindings.Add("Checked", DBTable,"Field")` just like the Textboxes. The checkboxes work properly displaying the correct data.

Only now when I try to add a row using `myCurrencyManager.AddNew()` it doesn't work. It does nothing except add a non-accessible row to the end of the datagridview. When I comment out the Checkbox DataBindings lines, everything works properly (without functioning checkboxes).

Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is the code:

```
Public Class frmRoutes
    Dim RoutesConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim JS1Adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim JS1Table As New DataTable("JOBSITES")
    Dim JSBS As BindingSource
    Dim JS1State As String = "Edit"

    Private Sub frmRoutes_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RoutesConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Microsoft\JS1TestDB.mdb")
        RoutesConnection.Open()
        Dim JobSitesCommand = New OleDbCommand _
        ("SELECT REF, STREET, CITY, SPEC, HELPER " +
        "FROM Jobsites ORDER BY REF", RoutesConnection)

        JS1Adapter.SelectCommand = JobSitesCommand
        JS1Adapter.Fill(JS1Table)

        JSBS = New BindingSource()
        JSBS.DataSource = JS1Table
        grdJobSites.DataSource = JSBS

        txtRef.DataBindings.Add("Text", JSBS, "REF")
        txtStreet.DataBindings.Add("Text", JSBS, "STREET")
        txtCity.DataBindings.Add("Text", JSBS, "CITY")
        'chkSpecial.DataBindings.Add("Checked", JSBS, "SPEC")  'THESE 2 CHECKBOX DATABINDINGS CAUSE THE 'ADDNEW' METHOD TO FAIL
        'chkHelper.DataBindings.Add("Checked", JSBS, "HELPER")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Try
            JSBS.AddNew()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error Adding a New row.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        JS1State = "Add"
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        JSBS.CancelEdit()
        JS1State = "View"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the default value for added "CheckBox" fields in database? Are you sure you not getting any exception when new row is added?

Comment: Don't use a `CurrencyManager` directly. Add a `BindingSource` to your form in the designer, bind your `DataTable` to the `BindingSource` and bind that to your controls. The `BindingSource` then does all the `CurrencyManager` did and more.

Comment: As is always the case with such issues, you should be creating a simple test project and isolating the specific functionality that is causing the issue. You don't need a database to populate a `DataTable`, which is what your controls are actually bound to, not an Access database. You can then experiment to find out what changes in the test project create the expected behaviour and the aberrant behaviour. If you still can;t solve the issue, at least you can provide us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: reply to @jmcilhinney - I have created a minimal version of my app and also am now using a BindingSource instead of currency manager but with the same result - if I have bound checkboxes, the AddNew method does not work properly. I am using Visual Studio for development. I can Copy and Paste the code but what about the Access DB file? Let me know how to proceed. Thanks again.

Comment: That data file is irrelevant. Your application is working with a `DataTable`. That's what is bound to your `BindingSource`. You can write code to populate a `DataTable` in any specific way you want, which means that you can test using the exact same data as is in the database or with any other data. My first thought is that you have nullable data in the database but your `CheckBoxes` only represent two states. That's a bit of a guess but it's the first place I'd look. Also, the idea of an MRE is that we can reproduce your issue but you haven't provided us with the example. Remember MINIMAL.

Comment: Reply to @jmcilhinney - I have added the minimal code to the Question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is exactly as I already said: nullable data. I just tested this code (an actual minimal example):

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim table As New DataTable

        With table.Columns
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
            .Add("Flag", GetType(Boolean))
        End With

        With table.Rows
            .Add("Peter", True)
            .Add("Paul", False)
            .Add("Mary", True)
        End With

        BindingSource1.DataSource = table
        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "Name")
        CheckBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", BindingSource1, "Flag")
    End Sub

End Class
```

and an invalid cast exception occurred when adding a new row (via a `BindingNavigator`) because the `Flag` column contained `DBNull.Value` by default and that cannot be cast as type `Boolean`, which is required for the `Checked` property. There are two potential solutions. The best one depends on whether you might want to be able save null values or not.

1. If you don't want to save null values then specify a default `Boolean` value for that column. That would probably be `False` but may be `True` if you want it. That way, when a new row is added, that column already contains a `Boolean` value that is compatible with the `Checked` property. In my example, this:

```vb
.Add("Flag", GetType(Boolean))
```

becomes this:

```vb
.Add("Flag", GetType(Boolean)).DefaultValue = False
```

In your case, you'd have to get the appropriate column from the `DataTable` after populating it and set that property.

2. Set the `ThreeState` property of the `CheckBox` to `True`, bind to the `CheckState` property instead of the `Checked` property and do your own translation between nullable `Boolean` data in the data source and `CheckState` values in the control. Making that change to my example might look like this:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents checkStateBinding As Binding

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim table As New DataTable

        With table.Columns
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
            .Add("Flag", GetType(Boolean))
        End With

        With table.Rows
            .Add("Peter", True)
            .Add("Paul", False)
            .Add("Mary", True)
        End With

        BindingSource1.DataSource = table
        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "Name")

        checkStateBinding = New Binding("CheckState", BindingSource1, "Flag")

        CheckBox1.DataBindings.Add(checkStateBinding)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckStateBinding_Format(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs) Handles checkStateBinding.Format
        'Convert from nullable Boolean to CheckState.
        If TryCast(e.Value, DBNull) Is DBNull.Value Then
            e.Value = CheckState.Indeterminate
        ElseIf CBool(e.Value) Then
            e.Value = CheckState.Checked
        Else
            e.Value = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckStateBinding_Parse(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs) Handles checkStateBinding.Parse
        'Convert from CheckState to nullable Boolean.
        Select Case DirectCast(e.Value, CheckState)
            Case CheckState.Indeterminate
                e.Value = DBNull.Value
            Case CheckState.Checked
                e.Value = True
            Case CheckState.Unchecked
                e.Value = False
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

The `Binding` raises its `Format` event when it needs to get data from the data source for the control and its `Parse` event when it needs to get data from the control for the data source. If types and/or values don't match up between the two, you can do your own translation.